# Adding "All" option to a prompt Pentaho dashboard?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I added a prompt in pentaho dashboard. And I want to add 'ALL' category to that prompt which means when I select "ALL", it shouldn't filter data, it should get all the data under the selected category. Could you guys please help me?

Answer (score 0):

For that use the Type SQL List and "All" as value (Take care to case sensitive). An example Query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'All' AS VAL, 'ALL TERRITORIES' AS DESC FROM customer_w_ter
UNION ALL
select DISTINCT TERRITORY, TERRITORY from customer_w_ter
```

Comment: And in MDX you can do the equivalent thing by either doing a union between the All member and the set you want or by using the Descendants function 1 level below together with the self_and_before tag.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Christopher
I used following postgresql query to get the data.

`select 'All' as accountclass
,status
,count(guaccountid) as count
 from sms_accountinformation 
group by status
union
select distinct accountclass
,status
,count(guaccountid)as count
from sms_accountinformation 
group by accountclass,status 
order by accountclass,status`

Is there any alternatives without hardcoding?

data set looks like as follows

`"All";"Active";2288
"All";"PD";257
"All";"TD";777
"Customer";"Active";2275
"Customer";"PD";152
"Customer";"TD";359
"Dealer";"Active";13
"Dealer";"PD";105
"Dealer";"TD";418`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in your query is to add an extra row with "**ALL**" data. Its not required to do a group by clause when writing the query for the ALL section. Check the below code *(hope it will be clearer)*:

```
select distinct 
accountclass,
status,
count(guaccountid)as count 
from sms_accountinformation 
group by accountclass,status order by accountclass,status

union

select 'ALL' as accountclass,
'ALL' as status,
'ALL' as count
from sms_accountinformation
```

This will fetch you a result set with 'ALL' as one more row which you can use it in your filter list.

Hope it helps:)